# How to read SQL Server COUNT from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the count for a table using C# `SqlDataReader` but I keep getting

> invalid attempt to read when no data is present

My code:

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DB].[dbo].[myTable]";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlComman(sql, connectionString);
SqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int count = mySqlDataReader.GetInt32(0); // Here is where I get the error.
```

I know I have a valid connection to the database because I can read and write to it in many places, what's special about the `COUNT(*)` that I cannot read it properly? How do I get the `int count` to be populated?

Comment: give an alias to count(*).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to read it:

```
if (mySqlDataReader.Read()) {
  count = mySqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

```
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

which is defined as:

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar is what you require.