# user level login C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Hi I am working on a login form with user level. Each account has two types of user-level. A and B where in A is Administrator and B is Employee. I can't seem to get the login right because I can still log in to the form using the Employee account. Please see my code.

```
private bool validate_login(string user, string pass, string pos) //sql check
    {
        db_connection();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass GROUP BY Position=@Position";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", pos);

        cmd.Connection = connect;

        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

 private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //LOGIN
    {
        try
        {               
            string user = textBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox2.Text;
            string pos = "A";

            if (user == "" || pass == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Did you input something? I doubt it.");
                return;
            }

            bool r = validate_login(user, pass, pos);
            /*bool s = validate_pos(pos);*/

            if (r)
            {                                   
               newMainMenu nmm = new newMainMenu();
               nmm.Show();
               this.Hide();
               logs.LogThatShit_LogIn();                                                                                                                                
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong username and/or password!", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e2.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have tried a lot of queries but I still can't get it right. Can you please tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What's that `GROUP BY` supposed to do? Why are you not adding position to the filter?

Comment: There is no code which checks for user type. Without that it won't work

Comment: I am trying to tell the query to select Username and Password with only a Position of A. I have tried `SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username="admin", Password="1234", Position="A"` but it gives me an SQL syntax error

Comment: `SELECT * .... GROUP BY Position` is bad SQL https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `GROUP BY Position=@Position` would simply group by `TRUE`/`FALSE` depending on whether the user is in the specified group. It doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: try follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546906/how-to-read-sql-server-count-from-sqldatareader, have you triied use count in sql query?

Comment: @NoxEternal Well then concat your conditions with `AND` - as you would do in any language and have already done with username and password.

Comment: @NoxEternal That's because it should be `WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password AND Position=@Position`... never mind the clear-text password security issue

Comment: Instead of `Group BY`, do WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass `AND Position=@Position`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto will give it a try now

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto worked!! Please post ur answer so I can mark it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Danger. You're storing your passwords unhashed (unencrypted). If you do that your application  **will** be hacked. The network is crawling with cybercriminals' bots looking for insecure sites. Please don't invent your own password verification. Dotnet has some good examples / templates for doing this right.

Answer (score -2):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass GROUP BY Position=@Position";
```

please write `Position=@pos`